# Premature EOF while reading JPG using itext

Tags: java, itext, jpeg

When attempting to include some jpeg files into a PDF using iText I get an error:
    **Premature EOF while reading JPG**

The images are loaded from android phones and most can be embedded into the pdf file, however some can not.

```
PushbuttonField ad = pdfForm.getNewPushbuttonFromField(fieldName);
if(ad != null) {
    ad.setLayout(PushbuttonField.LAYOUT_ICON_ONLY);
    ad.setProportionalIcon(true);
    try {
        ad.setImage(Image.getInstance(basePath + "/" + r.value));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Image error detail", e);
    }
    pdfForm.replacePushbuttonField(fieldName, ad.getField());
}
```

The error occurs during setImage at: com.itextpdf.text.Jpeg.processParameters(Jpeg.java:219)
iText version is: 5.5.5

I have put an image that causes the error onto a public dropbox folder: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/46349359/image.jpg
The image is 1.6 MB and is displayed without a problem in html or using other image display tools.

Comment: But is the image present in the specified location?

Comment: Yes it is present.

Comment: Following up on my previous comment I ran some tests where I renamed the file so it would not be found.  The error reported was then java.io.FileNotFoundException.

Comment: Confirmed its a duplicate question.   Thanks Amedee.  I ran imagemagick:  convert x.jpg y.jpg.   The resulting y.jpg file was accepted by iText.   I guess I have a workaround although in most cases this is an unnecessary step.  I think that iText should be able to read these files as other image processing applications can.

Comment: Actually with imagemagick the following will do the trick:  convert x.jpg x.jpg

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Amedee this question was a duplicate. The specific resolution that has worked for me is to:

1. install imageMagick
2. Prior to adding image file image.jpg into a PDF using iText run: 
        "convert image.jpg image.jpg"
3. Then add the jpeg